# Apache POI clearing freeze/split panes

Tags: java, apache-poi

Does anyone know how to clear/remove any existing freeze or split panes on a sheet with Apache POI?

I tried creating a new freeze pane at (-1,-1), but it appears POI will automatically change that to (0,0), which means that the first row and column are still frozen.

Fyi I'm using the HSSF and XSSF API's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downloaded the new version (3.8 beta 3) and it looks like they've reconciled the problem. The row/column of the freeze pane isn't frozen anymore (it use to be).

Now setting anything less than 0 will default to (0,0), but (0,0) does indeed turn off the freeze/split panes.. However, if no freeze pane currently exists (or if it's already at (0,0)), then you'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
try
{
    sheet.createFreezePane(0,0);
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    System.out.println("previously didn't have a freeze pane.");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't get an IOOB when creating a freeze pane, so it's likely worth opening a new bug in the POI bugzilla for this so it gets fixed!